# HTML Positioning Issue

Tags: html, css, positioning, margin

I'm trying to figure out why my top menu navigation is not positioning correctly at the following page. It adjusted unexpectedly when I added an Aweber sign-up box script.  I'm just confused as to how this is affecting the top of my page.

Here's the link:  http://www.richmindonline.com/index1.html

Any help would be appreciated, as this is for a client!  Thank you!

Comment: Looks fine to me, what brwoser are you using?

Comment: I'm using IE9 and the center table is being pushed down by 5px or so on my browser.

Comment: When I say 'adjusted unexpectedly', I mean that when I remove the Aweber script, the center navigation bar(in IE9) lines up correctly with the outside navigation images.  When I add the script it is offset downward by 5px or so

Comment: Yes, I agree tables should not have been used - and I wasn't the one who built the site.  But none of the other pages act in this way, as they don't contain the Aweber script.  Whenever I replace the script with a regular image, the navigation jumps back into the correct position.  FYI....I only uploaded the files tied to the homepage, so you won't be able to view the other pages correctly if you wanted to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I believe that I found the problem. Just after the `img` tag pointing to `images/custom-window-treatments-tx.jpg`, there is a bunch of whitespace. Remove all of it, making that whole `td` look like this:

```
<td valign="top"><img border="0" src="images/custom-window-treatments-tx.jpg" width="950" height="40"></td>
```